# string parts seperated by ; to ASCII written in a new string

Tags: string, lua, ascii

Something like that is coming in:

```
str="Hello;this;is;a;text"
```

What I do want as result is this:

```
result="72:101:108:108:111;116:104:105:115;..."
```

which should be the Text in ASCII.

Comment: `string.gsub(str, "[^;]", function(c) return tostring(string.byte(c))..':' end)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use string matching to get each word separated by `;` and then convert, concat:

```
local str = "Hello;this;is;a;text"
for word in str:gmatch("[^;]+") do
  ascii = table.pack(word:byte(1, -1))
  local converted = table.concat(ascii, ":")
  print(converted)
end
```

The output of the above code is:

```
72:101:108:108:111
116:104:105:115
105:115
97
116:101:120:116
```

I'll leave the rest of work to you. Hint: use `table.concat`.

Comment: thanks alot...that should help to make the next steps...as I mentioned...I'm a full rookie in lua

Comment: Okay...I got way further, but I can't find how to return a string made up of two seperate strings like str=str1&" "&str2

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, which exploits that fact that `gsub` accepts a table where it reads replacements:

```
T={}
for c=0,255 do
    T[string.char(c)]=c..":"
end
T[";"]=";"

str="Hello;this;is;a;text"
result=str:gsub(".",T):gsub(":;",";")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
function convert(s)
  return (s:gsub('.',function (s)
                       if s == ';' then return s end
                       return s:byte()..':'
                     end)
           :gsub(':;',';')
           :gsub(':$',''))
end

print(convert 'Hello;this;is;a;text')
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding certain character or string (such as ";") can be done by using `string.find` - https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html

Converting character to its ASCII code can be done by `string.byte` - https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html

What you need to do is build a new string using two functions mentioned above. If you need more string-based functions please visit official Lua site: https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I got way further, but I can't find how to return a string made up of two seperate strings like

```
str=str1&" "&str2
```

Comment: Ask a separate question. But you want the [string concatenation operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.6).